# Changing the button text, when a button is clicked w/ Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using latest version of Bootstrap and the built-in accordion feature, is there a way to change the text of the button to something different?

For instance: I have a button which displays the text 'Find Cafe', when clicked the accordion opens up and a list is shown. However, I want the text to change to display close.

I'm thinking I should use the `click` and `html` functions, but not sure how to arrange them.

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Find Cafe
            </a>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                 <div class="accordion-inner">
                    Anim pariatur cliche...
                 </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $('.collaspe').collapse();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You woudn't use Bootstrap for this. You'd simply use jQuery:

```
$('a.accordion-toggle').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).next('.accordion-body').hasClass('in') ) {
        $(this).text('Close');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Find Cafe');
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change the text to close.

Comment: Without a demo I can't begin to troubleshoot. This is pretty basic jQuery and should work.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled one of the targeting classes. Its works great. Thank you. Answer accepted!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have a question. Notice it doesn't work when more than 1 modal is open. How can I have it when more than one is open?

Comment: That's a very open-ended question, especially since modals haven't been mentioned to this point. You may need to change from click() to on(click) if elements are being created dynamically.

Comment: Right. I was talking about the accordion. I have about 5 links which collapse and open. When you open one and one another, the close doesn't work? That's what I meant to write.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this without JS also

```
.toggle-accordion:before {

   content:'see more'

}

.toggle-accordion[aria-expanded="true"]:before {

    content:'close';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using jquery

```
  $('#your-button-id').click(function(){
    $(this).text(function(i,old){
        return old=='Find Cafe' ?  'Close' : 'Find Cafe';
    });
});
```

Clean & Simple :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need configure individual text in template, separating the presentation from functionality.

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="collapse"]', function() {
   console.log(this);
  var _self = $(this);
  var _content = $(_self.attr('data-target'));
  var _originalText = _self.attr('data-text');

  if ( _content.hasClass('in') ) {
      _self.text(_self.attr('data-textexp'));
  } else {
      _self.text(_self.attr('data-text'));
  }
});
```